# Getting "Sorry! The configured backend (pro) does not know about ionic upload" When trying to upload the Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cloud

I'm trying to upload the App I built to my Ionic Pro account. 
I've linked my account and added the SSH keys but after running ionic upload I'm getting this error

[ERROR] Sorry! The configured backend (pro) does not know about ionic upload.

### This is My Ionic Info

cli packages: (/home/jos/Desktop/helloapp/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 
Gulp CLI    : not installed globally
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v6.11.0
npm               : 3.10.10 
OS                : Linux 3.13
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `ionic.config.json` file please? I am wondering if you have an "app_id" set.

Answer (score 1):

`ionic upload` doesn't work with backend pro, you have to create an app
on https://dashboard.ionicjs.com/apps and there will be a setup guide :)